# New page opens in new window, not new tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs

I have a site consisting of a frameset with two frames.  One of the frames opens a new document ala...

```
var myWin= open("","ImgWindow","status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes");
  myWin.document.open();
```

My Mozilla Firefox 3.0.19 is configured to open new pages in tabs, not windows.

Firefox opens the document in a new Window, not a tab.  IE and Opera open the document in a new tab.

Is there something I can do to cause the document to open in a new tab in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction) might help you.

With default settings, if you invoke window.open() without the third parameter, firefox will open the window in a new tab, otherwise in a new window.

Comment: That actually makes sense as the various bars couldn't be changed.