# FireFox Toolbar Open Window in new Tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, window.open

I have a Toolbarbutton

```
<toolbarbutton context="TabMenue" id="esbTb_rss_reader" label="News" type="menu">
```

with a Context menue which comes up when the button is right clickt

```
<menupopup id="TabMenue" >
    <menuitem label="New Tab" oncommand="esbTb_loadURLNewTab()"/>
</menupopup>
```

so this function should open the new window in a new tab

```
function esbTb_loadURLNewTab() {
    window.open(ClickUrl,'name'); }
```

I don't get it working that the new Window is showing up in a new tab it always opens a new firefox window.

I tried also like described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660192/new-page-opens-in-new-window-not-new-tab-in-firefox) to set the browser.link.open_newwindow and browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction preferences but that doesn't bringt anything.
And I tried it with all Target attributes which came in my mind.

So I'm grateful for any hints, tips what ever this is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help: [*Opening a URL in a new tab*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Opening_a_URL_in_a_new_tab).

But to give a start (more or less copy&paste):

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var recentWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
recentWindow.delayedOpenTab(url, null, null, null, null);
```